# Selenium-Watir webdriver test run failing only in Windows7(32 or 64 bit) and passing in Windows8 (32 or 64 bit)

Tags: windows, selenium, xpath, watir, watir-webdriver

We use watir-webdriver with ruby to automate the web application. While I came across an issue that my test run is passing in Windows 8 environment and failing in Windows 7 environment.
 Generally when we complete the scripting of automation, we test them on Virtual machines of Win-7 and Win-8 environments.

There is a mouse hovering action in my scripts, which is failing in windows 7 and passing in Windows 8. When I check it manually,it is working fine.

There is one strange behaviour I observed is, If I open the VM(Windows 7) (through Remote desktop),while test run is going on the same test is passing.

[image: here is the section I have tried to automate]

[image: Here is the DOM screenshot]

After cliking on 'AZ' button shown in above screenshot, I'm performing mouse hover action on'Date/time' option. Then trying to click on 'Ascending' option. The same test passed in Win-8 environment, but in Win-7 selenium is unable to identify 'Ascending' option, So it is failing.
After Clicking on 'AZ' button, fetching 'Date/Time' element reference and then  I'm performing the hover action as below:

```
element.hover
```

Below are the different Xpaths I have tried:

```
orderXpath = "(//ul[@class = 'submenu hide_sort_submenu']//a[contains(text(),'Ascending')])[1]"
orderXpath = "//ul[@class = 'submenu hide_sort_submenu' and contains(@style,'display: inline')]//a[contains(text(),'Ascending')]"
```

Then I'm performing Click operation

```
orderElement.click
```

Anyone came across this kind of issue?

Comment: First of all, you can't use several classes separated by spaces in most cases, so use contains with @class definition. Second, it's a very bad practice on selecting something containing a text. As for me I also prefer css selectors, as they are better and easier to support. Clicking will look like:  `@browser.element(:css => "ul#sort_menu_0 a[id*=asc]").click`

Comment: @Stanjer I have also used id attribute in the xpath, still I am facing same issue